# How long does it take to receive funds that show in internal transactions

Tags: internal-transactions

When I send a transaction and it shows in Internal txns, how long do I take to receive the funds in the wallet I sent it to?

Comment: Once a transaction is succesfuily mined the changes should be reflected immediately. Some exchanges require between 12 and 30 confirmations to accepts deposits.

Comment: How long will it take for transaction to show the funds in my wallet?

Comment: It depends on the wallet. I think most show any change immediately.